# Magento 2 - Import no error, no products uploading

Tags: mysql, magento, import, magento2, importerror

We have created an import to the website. It has imported the first 100 rows, then not imported any further. There is no errors and it is reading the rows upon checking the data.

We have tried removing all the first 100 successful products from the file and importing. It then imports successfully but when checking the import history, it shows 0 created, 0 updated, 0 errors.

I cannot seem to find the problem anywhere online.

I have checked the data in Notepad and there is no visual errors or breaks in the CSV.

Comment: Do you use magmi?

Comment: No, just standard magento import. Magmi doesn't support 2.1